# How to disable post-install messages from rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm tired of seeing silly messages like this, after installing gems:

```
Post-install message from httparty:
When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
```

In a quick scan of the [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/) I found no option to disable post-install messages.  I'm hoping to be able to configure this in my `~/.gemrc`.

Comment: Those messages come from the gems themselves as their configurator gizmo runs. Why not redirect STDOUT's output to a file? `gem install foo > ~/gem_install.log`. `gem install` is *supposed* to honor `-q` or `--quiet` to silence output, but it didn't work when I tested it.

Comment: Doesn't look available... Try nuke this [line](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/installer.rb#L241)

Comment: Perhaps +1 this PR: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/pull/321

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To ignore all post-install messages, in all projects:

```
bundle config --global ignore_messages true
```

Documentation:

> ignore_messages (BUNDLE_IGNORE_MESSAGES): When set, no post install messages will be printed. To silence a single gem, use dot notation like ignore_messages.httparty true.
>   https://bundler.io/v1.13/man/bundle-config.1.html

Answer (score 4):

[This gem will disable all post install messages of other gems.](https://github.com/tpope/gem-shut-the-fuck-up)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using bundler they added an option for that, just

> bundle config ignore_messages.httparty true

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend disabling them.  Granted HTTParty's isn't useful, but the reason they are there is to tell you something important about upgrades, etc.

If it were me, I would fork httparty's gem, remove the message, and submit a pull request pointing out that it's not helpful and increases the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: I appreciate your perspective, but this doesn't answer my question and would have been better as a comment. Thanks!

Comment: It's been pull-requested many times, to no avail :( https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/pull/321

Comment: @PaulAnnesley Well that's just sad :(