# Why does ruby-filemagic-0.7.2 throw this message when finished installing

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to ruby and bundler.
I run bundle install on an app and got this result on console.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies........
Using rake 12.3.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
[...]
Using carrierwave 2.1.0
Fetching ruby-filemagic 0.7.2
Installing ruby-filemagic 0.7.2 with native extensions
Fetching carrierwave-magic 0.0.4
Installing carrierwave-magic 0.0.4
[...]
Bundle complete! 34 Gemfile dependencies, 101 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
Post-install message from ruby-filemagic:

ruby-filemagic-0.7.2 [2017-07-02]:

* Fix segfault on <tt>buffer(nil)</tt> when compiled with GCC (pull request
  #24 by Yuya Tanaka)
```

It's not a problem for running ,I think, but just to know why does the gem throw this pull request result.
Is it important to throw this message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using version 0.7.2. The author of that gem included a postinstall hook for the gem that prints the message:

> - Fix segfault on buffer(nil) when compiled with GCC (pull request #24 by Yuya Tanaka)

This is the same message seen in the gem's [changelog](https://github.com/blackwinter/ruby-filemagic/blob/master/ChangeLog#L9-L12).

Is it important? No, and most gem authors do not include postinstall messages. Why does it throw it? You can read some discussion about messages at [How to add a (pre/post)_install_hook to ruby gems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33565367/3784008).

If you'd like to disable these messages you can read more at [How to disable post-install messages from rubygems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21584349/3784008).

Finally, for a more detailed review of these messages you can read more at [A Guide to Ruby Gem Post-Install Messages](https://brandonhilkert.com/blog/ruby-gem-post-install-message/).